# Define a generic trait with a function that returns a collection of types

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a Scala trait that is used as the base trait for a number of parsers. I have a number of case classes that will store the parsed datasets. All of these case classes extend the Parseable trait.

Some of the classes will return

```
Array[C <: Parseable]
```

others

```
Dataset[C <: Parseable]
```

How do I define the Parser trait so that the parse() function returns either of the above data structures?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on *All of these case classes extend the Parseable trait.*? Can you give a concrete example of a parser? Case classes extending parsable traits feels a bit unnatural to me.

Comment: I'll try! I have a number of different text files with pipe delimited data. Each of the files needs to be parsed differently, so I am trying to create a set of parsers that will each extend the Parser trait. The end result of the parsing of a file will be a case class containing the parsed data. Each of the case classes extends the Parseable trait. For various reasons the list of case classes generated by the parser could be an Array or Spark dataset, hence the need for the generic return type. I want to make sure that the returned list can only be subtypes of Parseable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trait Parser[A[_], B <: Parseable]{

      def parse(s:String): A[B]

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling to figure out how to then apply this to my parser code, finally figured out the following: object DemographicParser extends Parser[Array, Patient] {

  def parse(filename: String)(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): Array[Patient] = ...